# By Whom and when is mailbox_transport and local_transport of postfix used?

Tags: email

I am learning postfix. But I cannot figure out what is the difference between mailbox_transport and local_transport?
I could understand mailbox_transport expand mail address by local alias and .forward alias before it sends a mail to LMTP client/server but local_transport sends it to LMTP client/server directly. However because I don't know which process uses mailbox_transport or local_transport and when they are used, I cannot figure out how I use them properly.
 Please someone teach me it.
 Thank you very much.